# Using limit in sqlite SQL statement in combination with order by clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Will the following two SQL statements always produce the same result set?**

```
 1. SELECT * FROM MyTable where Status='0' order by StartTime asc limit 10

 2. SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable where Status='0' order by StartTime asc) limit 10
```

Comment: Is this question specifically for SQLite?

Comment: The question is primarily targeted on SQLite. But if an answer also tells me something about using the Oracle `rownum` in the same scenario, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. First because the `StartTime` column may not have `UNIQUE` constraint. So, even the first query may not always produce the same result - with itself!

Second, even if there are never two rows with same StartTime, the answer is still **negative**.

The first statement will always order on `StartTime` and produce the first 10 rows. The second query may produce the same result set but only with a primitive optimizer that doesn't understand that the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is redundant. And only if the execution plan includes this ordering phase.

The SQLite query optimizer may (at the moment) not be very bright and do just that (no idea really, we'll have to check the source code of SQLite*). So, it may appear that the two queries are producing identical results all the time. Still, it's not a good idea to count on it. You never know what changes will be made in a future version of SQLite.

I think it's not good practice to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, in any DBMS. It may work now, but you never know how long these queries will be used by the application. And you may not be around when SQLite is upgraded or the DBMS is changed.

(*) @Gareth's link provides the execution plan which suggests that current SQLite code is dumb enough to execute the redundant ordering.

Comment: I, like the primitive optimizer, don't understand why the `order by` in the second query is redundant. Could you please explain?

Comment: A subquery like that returns a (derived) table. Tables, (base tables, views or derived ones) have no implicit order. Some DBMS do not even allow `ORDER BY` in derived subqueries and/or views.

Comment: I posted a [followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10430762/220636) concerning oracle and usage of `rownum`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but ordering subqueries is probably a bad habit to get into. You could feasibly add a further `ORDER BY` outside the subquery in your second example, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM Test
      ORDER BY ID ASC
     ) AS A
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

SQLite still performs the `ORDER BY` on the inner query, before sorting them again in the outer query. A needless waste of resources.

I've done an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/61e5b/4) to demonstrate so you can view the execution plans for each.

Comment: +1 for the execution plan that demonstrates how SQLite actually executes this.