# Using rownum in oracle SQL statement in combination with order by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

**Which of the following two SQL statements will return the desired result set** (i.e. the ten rows with Status=0 and the highest StartTimes)?

**Will both statements always return the same result set** (StartTime is unique)?

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Status=0 
AND ROWNUM <= 10 
ORDER BY StartTime DESC

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE Status=0 
    ORDER BY StartTime DESC
) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

**Background**

My DBAdmin told me that the first statement will *first* limit the table to 10 rows and than order those random rows by StartTime, which is definitly not what I want.
From what I learned in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429914/220636), the order by clause of the second statement is redundant and could be removed by an optimizer, which is also not what I want.

---

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10429738/220636) concering the `limit` clause in a query to a SQLite database and am interested in understanding any differences to the above statements (using `limit` Vs `rownum`) used with an oracle db.

Comment: The 1st query doesn't even parse. You may want to edit your question.

Comment: and the second will need an alias.

Comment: Sorry for the errors. I fixed and verified statement one against our database. The second statement should be syntactically correct.

Comment: Related: [How to select the nth row in a SQL database table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table)

Comment: Also: [Wikipedia: FETCH FIRST clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause)

Comment: For Oracle: [ROW_NUMBER vs ROWNUM](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

Comment: The order by clause will not be removed by the Oracle optimiser in these circumstances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Second Query will work

Because in the first ,the first ten rows with Status 0 are selected and then the order by is done in that case the first ten rows fetched need not be in the highest order